# 'Enter PIN for authenticator' Issue related to SSH

Tags: macos, github, ssh

## Brief

I attempted to generate a SSH key for my Github on a **Macbook Pro**. Yet I encountered the 'Enter PIN for authenticator' issue when I progressed to the step of adding it to the ssh-agent. The bizarre asking is from the following command:

```
$ ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter PIN for authenticator:
```

which I totally have no idea what I should type into for this asking. Yet as I typed with the following command, everything just worked as [this page](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) revealed.

```
$ /usr/bin/ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Identity added: /Users/${user_name}/.ssh/id_rsa (your_email@example.com)
```

Why there exists this kind of difference ? What exactly you need to type for the asking of 'Enter PIN for authenticator:' ?

## Some Info

1. version information

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.3p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020

$ sw_vers -productVersion
10.15.6
```

2. I generated the key with the ed25519 algorithm.

Comment: Do you have 2fa enabled on your GitHub account?

Comment: @AvivLo nope, I havn't enabled 2fa.

Comment: This is weird. It's asking for some auth code. It means there must be some sort of 2FA in place somewhere.

Comment: So far I only know the location of `ssh-add` is at `/usr/local/bin/ssh-add` which would ask that auth while `/usr/bin/ssh-add` works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 107):

If you use this command

```
$ ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

you will be asked to enter the PIN for authentication
so instead of that use

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Using +K worked on my mac os install but this solution worked on my ubuntu install. Is the variance simply because of the different installs or is there a more in-depth reason?

In either case, thank you!

Comment: On raspberry Pi OS (32) removing the -K resulted in a request for the passphrase which is what I was expecting. I was not expecting to be asked for a pin!

Answer (score 35):

You have a second (Brew-installed?) ssh-add in your shell's $PATH which is not the same as the Apple version. In the Apple version `-K` stores the password in your keychain, so you don't have to type it every time. In the non-Apple version `-K` "Loads resident keys from a FIDO authenticator."

The `ssh-add` at:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-add
```

is the Apple provided one, and will work with `-K`.

**Update for macOS Monterey (v12)**

The `-K` and `-A` flags are deprecated and have been replaced by the `--apple-use-keychain` and `--apple-load-keychain` flags, respectively.

Comment: Yes! I can confirm. The ssh-add on my PATH is `/usr/local/bin/ssh-add -> ../Cellar/openssh/9.0p1_1/bin/ssh-add` (see  `ls -l $(which ssh-add)`).  Github has docs that show using `/usr/bin/ssh-add` is possible to fix the problem even if you have both installed: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-ssh-add-illegal-option----k

Comment: The really important thing is to know if your installed version is brew openssh package or the Apple one. `ssh -V` should give you the answer as well.

Answer (score 29):

I have seen on - https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/add and found that if we use -'k' (small k) then it is asking about passpharase what I added during ssh key generaion.

for instance my passphrase while creating ssh key was - Pass@123#
after that when i exeute command -

```
$ssh-add -k ~/.ssh/id_rsa 
Enter passphrase for ~/.ssh/id_rsa: (typed here - Pass@123# and press enter)
Identity added: ~/.ssh/id_rsa (xxxxxxx@xxxx.com)
```

Comment: This `-k` command works for me on Debian11, thanks @Pravind Kumar

Comment: This worked for me on Fedora.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

as specified by the man ssh-add page, the `-K` option is:

> -K      Load resident keys from a FIDO authenticator.

so you basically tell it to use an authenticator.

Comment: So if you have 2fa enabled on your github account that would refer to the code in the Authenticator (app) that you have setup 2fa with?